# Capturing a screenshot and saving to a document with a Python background script

Tags: python, screenshot

I’m doing some testing activity which requires me to capture a screenshot of applications, database systems, etc. and save it to a document.

The whole activity has more than 50 screenshots. Is there a way in Python through which I can take a screenshot with a Windows shortcut key (for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and it appends the image to a document file?

I believe the Python program should be running in the background, like [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) in Unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing screen captures in [Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word) using a hotkey, you can use a combination of libraries.

- Use **win32gui** to open Word
- Use **python-docx** to update the document and save
- Use **[PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** to do the screen capture
- Use **keyboard** to listen for the hotkey

For this script to work, you will need to create the Word document before running the script.

```
# Need these libraries
# pip install keyboard
# pip install PyAutoGUI
# pip install python-docx
# pip install win32gui

import keyboard
import pyautogui
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
import win32gui
from PIL import ImageGrab

shotfile = "C:/tmp/shot.png"  # Temporary image storage
docxfile = "C:/tmp/shots.docx" # The main document
hotkey = 'ctrl+shift+q'  # Use this combination anytime while the script is running

def do_cap():
    try:
        print ('Storing capture...')

        hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()  # Active window
        bbox = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)  # Bounding rectangle

        # capture screen
        shot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=bbox) # Take a screenshot, active app
        # shot = pyautogui.screenshot() # Take a screenshot full screen
        shot.save(shotfile) # Save the screenshot

        # Append to the document. Doc must exist.
        doc = Document(docxfile) # Open the document
        doc.add_picture(shotfile, width=Inches(7))  # Add the image, 7 inches wide
        doc.save(docxfile)  # Update the document
        print ('Done capture.')
    except Exception as e:  # Allow the program to keep running
        print("Capture Error:", e)

keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, do_cap)  # Set hot keys

print("Started. Waiting for", hotkey)

keyboard.wait()   # Block forever
```

Comment: No problem. Please confirm the answer to get it off the "No Answer" list.

Answer (score 1):

The same code works when done with a few minor changes.
Thank you for the code in [Mike67's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315215/capturing-a-screenshot-and-saving-to-a-document-with-a-python-background-script/63317831#63317831). However, I faced some challenges and sorted out a few things, and the below code works perfectly fine. Screenshots are captured with a timestamp.

```
hotkey = 'win+prtscn' # Use this combination anytime while script is running
```

## To take a screenshot full screen with a timestamp

```
shot = pyautogui.screenshot() # To take a screenshot full screen with a timestamp
```

## Append to the document. Doc must exist.

```
    docxfile = r'C:\tmp\shots.docx' # The main document. I ADDED THIS STATEMENT
```

Only the above statements added or changed with that code work perfectly.

The hotkey [Windows key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key) along with that [Prt Sc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_Screen) key could also be used. While the code is in debugging mode, `win+prtscn` (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd>) will store the image in the location specified in the code as well as the default location pictures screenshots folder.

After stopping debug mode, `win+prtscn` will store images only in the default location screenshots folder.

However, hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> when utilized after stopping debug mode then the *shot.png* image file will have an image without a timestamp.
During debug mode when the above hotkeys are used, *shot.png* will have an image along with the timestamp.

Comment: To create new blank word doc in path     
"""
    except:
        document = docx.Document()
        #document.save('CKS1.docx')
        document.save('C:/tmp/CKS0.docx')
        print ('Doc created.')     # Doc created

        #doc1 = Document('CKS0.docx') # open document
        #doc1.add_picture(shotfile, width=Inches(7))  # add image, 7 inches wide
        #doc1.save('CKS0.docx')  # update document
        print ('Done capture.')
        print("Previous file was corrupted or didn't exist - new file was created.")
"""

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35102312)

Answer (score 1):

To create a new blank document:

```py
except:
    document = docx.Document()
    #document.save('CKS1.docx')
    document.save('C:/tmp/CKS0.docx')
    print ('Doc created.')     # Doc created

    #doc1 = Document('CKS0.docx') # open document
    #doc1.add_picture(shotfile, width=Inches(7))  # add image, 7 inches wide
    #doc1.save('CKS0.docx')  # update document
    print ('Done capture.')
    print("Previous file was corrupted or didn't exist - new file was created.")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35116678)